# Google Maps API v3 WEB JS direction between two static markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, oop, google-maps-api-3

I need some help with the Google Maps WEb JS API. I'm diving into it for the first time and now I'm stuck.

I want to set a static direction of two static markers on a Google Map.

I'm trying to write the code in OOP.

The map is getting load on my webpage, but I'm not getting to see the "markers" and the "direction".

Please some help and advice!

```js
var WEB = WEB || {};

(function() {

 'use strict'

 //controller init object
 WEB.controller = {

  init: function() {
   // initialize APP objects
   google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', WEB.googleMaps.init());   
  }
 };

 WEB.googleMaps = {

  init: function() {

   WEB.googleMaps.directionsDisplay();
   console.log('1. init directionsDisplay');

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.295042, 4.867158),
       zoom: 14,
       maxZoom: 15,
       minZoom: 13,
       draggable: false
   });
   
   console.log('2. init map');

   WEB.googleMaps.directionsDisplay(map);
   console.log('3. init directionsDisplay in map');

   console.log('4. init calc route');
   WEB.googleMaps.calcRoute();
  },

  directionsDisplay: function() {
   new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  },

  directionsService: function(){
   new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  },

  calcRoute: function() {

   WEB.googleMaps.directionsService();
   console.log('5. init directionsService');

   var start = new google.maps.LatLng(XX.XXXXXX, XX.XXXXXX);
     var end = new google.maps.LatLng(XX.XXXXXX, XX.XXXXXX);
     console.log('6. set directions', start, end);

   var request = {
         origin: start,
         destination: end,
         travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
     };
     
     console.log('7. put directions in the service', request);
     WEB.googleMaps.directionsService(request, function(response, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
     console.log('7. DirectionsStatus is OK');         
          WEB.googleMaps.directionsDisplay(response);
       }            
     });
  }     
 };

 WEB.controller.init();

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="nl">

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <!-- GOOGLE MAPS API -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
</head>

<body class="">
    <header class="">
    </header>
    <main class="">
        <div id="map-canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; margin:0; padding:0; border:0;">
        </div>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code you're creating markers (assuming you mean instances of the Marker class).  And in your directionsDisplay function where you just do `new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();` that isn't going to do anything useful.  Assign the contents of that into a variable, i.e. `var directions = WEB.googleMaps.directionsDisplay();` and then change the function to actually return something, `return new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();`  Ditto with the directionsService

Comment: @duncan var start = new google.maps.LatLng(XX.XXXXXX, XX.XXXXXX);
     var end = new google.maps.LatLng(XX.XXXXXX, XX.XXXXXX);
     console.log('6. set directions', start, end);

   var request = {
         origin: start,
         destination: end,
         travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
     };

Comment: Those aren't [Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker), those are [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) points being passed into a directionsService.  I'm being pedantic but if you're wanting to get all OOP it helps to get the names you use to refer to your objects correct

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something more like this.

```
WEB.googleMaps = {
        init: function() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.295042, 4.867158),
                zoom: 14,
                maxZoom: 15,
                minZoom: 13,
                draggable: false
            });

            var directionsDisplay = WEB.googleMaps.getDirectionsDisplay(map);

            WEB.googleMaps.calcRoute(directionsDisplay);
        },

        getDirectionsDisplay: function(map) {
            return new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({map: map});
        },

        getDirectionsService: function(){
            return new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        },

        calcRoute: function(directionsDisplay) {
            var directionsService = WEB.googleMaps.getDirectionsService();

            var start = new google.maps.LatLng(XX.XXXXXX, XX.XXXXXX);
            var end = new google.maps.LatLng(XX.XXXXXX, XX.XXXXXX);

            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }                       
            });
        }                   
    };

    WEB.controller.init();
```

It helps to read this carefully: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions